# Are open balls always complete?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider a sequence $y_n$ inside some ball $B(x,l)$. Say the sequence converges to $y$.
We know that $ \|x - y_n \| \lt l $, Then $ \|x - y_n - y + y\| \lt l $,
 and therefore $ \|x - y\| - \|y_n - y\| \lt l $. Since the second term can be as small as possible, then one can state that $ \|x - y\| \lt l $, and hence $y$ should be inside the open ball.

I would really appreciate it if anyone can clarify where the mistake in my formalism is.

Comment: What if the sequence converges to a point in the boundary? Take $(0,1)$ and the sequence $x_n = 1/n$.

Comment: What can happen inside $\mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1)$ and even in $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$?

Comment: No: in fact they are if and only if $\dim V=0$.

Comment: Your proof only holds when $l-\lVert y-x \lVert > 0$, in which case $y$ lies in the ball and the case is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

That is incorrect.

**Counterexample:** Let $X=\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric and consider the open ball $(0,1).$ Then the sequence $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)_n$ can be shown to be Cauchy but its limit, namely $0$ is not inside the open ball.

**Edit:** Your mistake is going from $$\|x-y\|-\|y_n-y\|<l$$ to $$\|x-y\|<l.$$ In fact, taking the limit only gives $$\|x-y\|\leq l.$$ This is the major problem since $y$ may be on the boundary of the ball and not inside the ball.

The sequence $\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)_n$ is an example of this.

Another mistake is assuming that the sequence $(y_n)$ converges if it is Cauchy. This can only be concluded if your ambient normed space is complete, which is not an assumption you make in your question.

**Edit 2:** The first part of this answer is to OP's original question: If a Cauchy sequence is inside some ball, then isn't its limit also inside the ball, making the ball a complete subset?

Comment: I understand your example. And I would like to present my formalism of this problem, so that we can recognize where I am going wrong

Comment: You're wrong in concluding that if a Cauchy sequence is inside an open ball, then it's limit is also inside the ball.

Comment: The one who has asked is indeed wrong in the conclusion,but there is no problem with the triangle inequality part.Ineed $||x-y_{n}|| = ||(x-y)-(y_{n}-y)|| \geq ||x-y||-||y_n - y||$ so there is absolutely no problem to write $||x-y||< ||y-y_n||+l$.Infact,it's true,if one observes,you have $y$ on the boundary,so distance from $x$ to $y$ should always be less or equal to the sum of distances from $x$ to $y_n$ and then from $y_n$ to $y$.The mistake arises when the limit is taken,the fact that $||x-y||< ||y-y_n||+l$ implies that on taking limit,$||x-y||\leq l$,not just $<$.

Comment: @SaptakBhattacharya It seems I have not had my coffee today.

Comment: Can one prove that rigorously; for the general case?

Comment: @N.Koudsie Prove what, exactly? One can prove (using your arguments) that a closed ball of a complete space is complete. But this is not true in case the ball is open. To prove something is not true, a counterexample is a **rigorous** approach

Comment: One cannot prove that an open ball of a complete metric space is never complete,because that's simply not true.Consider any discrete metric space for example.A fancier example,if you are bored with discrete metric spaces,can be a non empty connected graph with the shortest path metric.In this case too,an open ball of radius $1/2$ around a vertex $v$ would contain just itself,and end up being complete.